# Perform Operation on field when Marshalled struct to json

Tags: json, go

I have the following struct:

```
type Message struct {
    DoubleMe    int     `json:"double_me"`
    Message     string  `json:"message"`
}
```

And a instance of it:

```
m := Message{5, "Hello, World!"}
```

My goal is to perform some operation to the `DoubleMe` field when it's marshaled to json, for example doubling it.  So the output would be:

```
{"double_me":10,"message":"Hello, World!"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't do that. JSON is the wire format. You work and manipulate Go variables of  type Message and you double the field and serialize once you have the value you want to serialize. Never think if JSON as a "data format".

Comment: @Volker In my use case it's not that json is being used as a "data format" it's that the rest API has to serve up the "display" of a number rather then how it's stored internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) on your struct, which is to define a custom marshaling logic, which may double the `DoubleMe` field.

See this example:

```
type Message struct {
    DoubleMe int    `json:"double_me"`
    Message  string `json:"message"`
}

func (m Message) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    m.DoubleMe *= 2

    type Message2 Message
    return json.Marshal(Message2(m))
}

func main() {
    m := Message{5, "Hello, World!"}
    data, err := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(data), err)
    fmt.Println("Original:", m)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_4MwoZBE1DW)):

```
{"double_me":10,"message":"Hello, World!"} <nil>
Original: {5 Hello, World!}
```

Some notes:

- If you need this to work backwards too (e.g. when unmarshaling, divide the value by 2), also implement [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) (left to the reader as an exercise).
- Even though we doubled the field, after the marshaling, the original value did not change. This is because the method has a non-pointer receiver, so inside the method only a copy is acquired and modified, but not the original value. If we would've used pointer receiver, we would have to take care of restoring it.
- Also note that a new type `Message2` is created and used inside the `MarshalJSON()` method. This is because we also used the `json` package to do the "usual" marshaling once we applied our custom logic. But if we would pass `m` to `json.Marshal()`, that would be an endless "recursion", because the `json` package would again call this `MarshalJSON()` method. Instead we created a `Message2` type having `Message` as its underlying type. This means `Message2` has zero methods (it does not implement `json.Marshaler`), so passing a value of `Message2` to `json.Marshal()` will not call this method again, and since it has `Message` as its underlying type, we can simply convert a value of type `Message` to `Message2`.